# User oriented dynamic URL not loading - Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

I'm having this issue where I can register and login users but when I go to view the data (as the signed in user) nothing will load. I've been struggling with it quite a bit and just can't figure it out. When I look at the Django error page it shows it is pulling the correct user but won't show it.

[Dynamic URL per user issue -
Django error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnGjE.png)

Here is the urls.py:

```html
from django.urls import path
from.import views


urlpatterns = [
path('',views.HomePage, name='HomePage'),
path('category/<slug:slug>', views.CategoryPage, name='image-date'),

path('<slug:slug_customer>/',views.Customer),
```

Here is the models.py:

```html
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django_resized import ResizedImageField
from django.utils import timezone
from uuid import uuid4
from django.urls import reverse

class User(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    #insert way to have user specific .csv link

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=200)    

class Image(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    altText = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    

    #ImageFields
    squareImage = ResizedImageField(size=[1000, 1000], crop=['middle', 'center'], default='default_square.jpg', upload_to='DB Pictures')
    
    #Related Fields
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Here is my views.py:

```html
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *

# Create your views here.

def HomePage(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()

    context = {}
    context['categories'] = categories

    return render(request, 'HomePage.html', context)


def CategoryPage(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    context = {}
    context['categories'] = categories

    return render(request, 'CategoryPage.html', context)


def DataPage(request, slug, slug_customer):
    # customer = Category.objects.get(user_name=slug_customer)
    category = Category.objects.get(slug=slug)
    images = Image.objects.filter(category=category)

    context = {}
    context['category'] = category
    context['image'] = images #sending backend of image and category to the front so it's dynamically loaded with each category and image

    return render(request, 'DataPage.html', context)

def Customer(request, slug_customer):
    obj = User.objects.get(slug=slug_customer)
    return render(request, "CategoryPage.html")
```

Here is my Github with the most recent code pushed if you want to see the entire project: https://github.com/ReubenNinan/CropDrone2.git

I think the issues mostly lie in LoginScreen/views.py; LoginScreen/models.py; LoginScreen/urls.py

You will know it works because it will show a very similar page to this:

[Dynamic URL per user issue - Django
Categories Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFXnj.png)

[Dynamic URL per user issue - Django
Album of photos after selecting date from categories page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LW7BR.png)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is over here:

```
def Customer(request, slug_customer):
    obj = User.objects.get(slug=slug_customer) # THIS LINE
    return render(request, "CategoryPage.html")
```

The user model you are using here is your own custom model and not the user model provided by django. To use it you need to import it as follows:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

This should resolve your issue. And also don't import everything at once use '*' it's a bad practise and just import the things you require.